# How do I exclude an exported JS file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript

I have a Node.js library package (let's call it "OasisLib") which has a file named `TypeGenerator.ts`.

The exact logic of what happens in the file is not relevant. But this needs to access files in filesystem while building the project. So, we used `let fs = require('fs')` to write some additional files to file system.

This OasisLib needs to be used in two different Node.js modules:

1. OasisUI - This is a React application
2. OasisLibExtension - This is another Node.js library that another team has to be able to implement, and in here we need to use TypeGenerator that is defined in OasisLib to generate additional files during build.

So, the OasisLib is used in both a UI package and a non-UI package and the `TypeGenerator` in base library package is only needed in extension library during build time. We have exported TypeGenerator in library package by adding it as an export in `index.ts`.

However, when I'm running the UI package, we are getting following error on homepage of UI:

```
ERROR in ../OasisLib/dist/src/gen/TypeGenerator.js 48:15-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Volumes/Code/OasisLib/src/OasisLib/dist/src/gen'
```

So, the JS file is being compiled even though I'm not using that file in UI package.

Here is what I'm trying to figure out. Is there any way to export TypeGenerator from OasisLib module, so that I can use it in LibExtensions package, but not cause issues in UI package?

Alternatively can I exclude a specific file when starting UI React application?

I tried adding following to OasisUI but this didn't solve the issue:

```
"exports": {
    "../OasisLib/dist/src/gen/TypeGenerator.js": {
      "ignore": true
    }
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
```

Package.json of OasisLib.

```
{
  "name": "@myorg/oasis-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && rm -rf node_modules",
    "generate-models": "node ./dist/src/gen/GenerateTypes.js && tsc",
    "build": "tsc && npm run generate-models",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build && npm run test",
    "test:watch": "vitest",
    "test": "vitest run --coverage --passWithNoTests",
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts start"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/src/*",
    "dist/types/*"
  ],
  "npm-pretty-much": {
    "runTest": "never"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ion-js": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "*",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.25",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "@vitest/browser": "^0.34.6",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^0.34.6",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vitest": "^0.34.6"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@types/react": ">=18",
    "@types/react-dom": ">=18",
    "react": ">=18",
    "react-dom": ">=18"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this what dev dependencies are for? If your OasisUI package uses the LibExtensions package as a dev dependency, then users of OasisUI will not run into this.

Comment: There are some classes that need to be used during runtime, so we can't completely make them into dev dependencies.

Comment: Can you split the dev-only stuff into its own package?

Comment: I'm trying to see if there is a any solution that avoids this. But in worst case I may end up having to do this.

Comment: "_We have exported TypeGenerator in library package by adding it as an export in index.ts._" that is probably what increases the chances of it being included by default even when you do not want to. You do not necessarily need to expose your API through a single entry point. Depending on your projects config and build engines, you may still be able to exclude it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have 3 projects:

- (A) OasisLib having both runtime objects (A1) and TypeGenerator (A2) for its own build, all exposed through a single `index.ts`
- (B) UI React app importing (A1)
- (C) Node lib extension using (A2) for its own build

Because (A2) is part of the *same* `index.ts` file as (A1), if (B) tries to import (A1) through this entry point, and it does not perform tree shaking, then indeed, it will include (A2) as well.

But you can expose (A1) and (A2) through separate entry points. The exact configuration depends on the build engine in your (A) project and its build steps.

That way, (A1) is unrelated to (A2) TypeGenerator (even though the latter may still import (A1) if needed), and (B) UI app can import (A1) separately from (A2).

While (C) can also import (A2) through the separate entry point.

---

If you use directly `tsc` to build the (A) library, and your `tsconfig.json` is not too fancy, it should already transpile each `.ts` file into their own `.js` and `.d.ts` files. Therefore, you can directly import them, as if each file is an entry point:

```
// In (C) build script
// Instead of:
import { TypeGenerator } from "@myorg/oasis-lib"; // Resolves to package.json > main, i.e. dist/index.js

// ...directly import the desired file:
import { TypeGenerator } from "@myorg/oasis-lib/dist/src/gen/TypeGenerator";
```

Now you can remove the mention of `TypeGenerator` from your `index.ts`, and (B) is no longer polluted by (A2).

---

You can even use the [`"exports"`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points) field in `package.json` to further tune your exposed API / entry points:

```json
// (A) package.json
{
  "name": "@myorg/oasis-lib",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/index.js"
    },
    "type-gen": {
      "types": "./dist/src/gen/TypeGenerator.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/src/gen/TypeGenerator.js"
    }
  }
}
```

```
// (B) UI app component file
import { RuntimeObject } from "@myorg/oasis-lib"; // Resolves to exports > . > types + default

// (C) lib extension build script file
import { TypeGenerator } from "@myorg/oasis-lib/type-gen"; // Resolves to exports > type-gen > types + default
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sounds reasonable and your understanding of our problem is spot on, we have one index.ts. I have updated package.json. How do I expose A1 and A2 through separate entry points? I've added package.json in the question. I don't think we are using any complex build. Is it possible to give an example of how separate entry points can be made?

Comment: Lot of useful information that I wasn't aware of. I have figured out a different way of doing things, which I will post as another answer. But your solution seems like better one. Accepted and Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with before I noticed the other answer, which I still recommend instead of this answer. But documenting here as an alternative solution.

I changed the `TypeGenerator.ts` to avoid any references to fs by moving the code that uses `fs` to another class. I only use writeFile method of `fs` so created a dummy object named writer with dummy writeFile method.

Previous code in TypeGenerator.ts

```
export function generateTypes(types: ConfigTypeDef[] = [], fs_module: any) {
  writer = require("fs");
  generate(types, writer);
}
```

New code without any references to `fs`.

```
let writer: { writeFile: (arg0: string, arg1: string, arg2: { (err: Error): void; (err: Error): void; (err: Error): void; }) => void; };

export function generateTypes(types: ConfigTypeDef[] = [], fs_module: any) {
  writer = fs_module;
  generate(types, writer);
}
```

The TypeGenerator is still exported as usual in OasisLib. When OasisLibExtension is calling this method, it passes the fs module. OasisUI package does not have the issue of fs anymore.